# linker ignores library linking

Tags: c, linker

I have a simple linker script, that links for armv7 processor. I didnt have a need for libc yet, so it was not really linked in. But now when i tried to compile some C sources i came across undefined references to memset which should be in libc.a that ships with compiler.

So what i did was `ld -Llib -lc` (i moved libc in to project's lib folder). and it still gave me undefined reference to memset.

Next i directly specified to use libc.a in linking with INPUT(libc.a), and still i get undefined reference.

And what finally worked is `ld $(objects) lib/libc.a`, and that linked it no problem. i looked at disassembly and everything is fine, it uses memset.

Can somebody explain to me what is happening here, i am still new to all this stuff :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you can assume it is $(Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and would be interesting for everyone new to armv7 programming.

First of all, even if it links fine you will end up in HardFault handler since ld will use libgcc which was not built for thumb.

Solution:
instead of a linker (ld) use gcc, for example

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -T linker.ld -O1 -nostartfiles -mthumb -o bin/prog.elf src/obj/boot.o src/obj/stm32f746_startup.o`

Very important here is `-mthumb` so your linker picks up the right libc/libgcc, or compile your own libc with thumb and link it with ld.